# how to get a list of the users connected in to a voice channel with discord.js / nodejs?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get a list / an array of users (username/id) connected to the voice channel of the one who launched the command. I feel like I'm on a good way but I don't find how to do this. for now, I tried `message.member.voice.channel.members` but It's a long list of information about who is in the channel. I only want their name / tag.

Comment: You can join Discord.js or Discord API server on Discord to meet experts live there. They are prompt at answering such questions.

Comment: Just use `Collecrion#map` and map each member by their tag.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    message.member.voice.channel.members.each(member=>{
       console.log(member.user.tag)
    })
```

for more info read official [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) documentation